# Select @ROW_NUMBER on each group by joining other tables and reset it

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question title might not be meant exactly of what I mean but I didn't know what to write tbh.

So let's get into the question. What I want to have is like the following

Table1

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| Code1   | LCode1  |
| Code2   | LCode2  |
| Code3   | LCode3  |
+---------+---------+
```

Table2

```
+---------+---------+
| Column3 | Column4 |
+---------+---------+
| LCode1  | string1 |
| LCode1  | string2 |
| LCode1  | string3 |
| LCode2  | String1 |
| LCode2  | String2 |
| LCode2  | String3 |
| LCode2  | String4 |
| LCode3  | String1 |
| LCode3  | String2 |
+---------+---------+
```

Selected Table should be like that...

```
+-------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Index | Column1 | Column2-3 | Column4 |
+-------+---------+-----------+---------+
|     0 | Code1   | LCode1    | string1 |
|     1 | Code1   | LCode1    | string2 |
|     2 | Code1   | LCode1    | string3 |
|     0 | Code2   | LCode2    | string1 |
|     1 | Code2   | LCode2    | string2 |
|     2 | Code2   | LCode2    | string3 |
|     3 | Code2   | LCode2    | string4 |
|     0 | Code3   | LCode3    | string1 |
|     1 | Code3   | LCode3    | string1 |
+-------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

I have tried to use ROW_NUMBER with a join statements between both tables but sadly I got no luck with that. It's only possible when I do use WHERE statement for specified Column2-3 value not all of them.
As example

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() AS Index, * FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Column2 = T2.Column3 Order By Index
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.column1 ORDER BY T2.column4) - 1 AS seqnum,
       T1.*, T2.*
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN
     Table2 T2
     ON T1.Column2 = T2.Column3
ORDER BY seqnum;
```

`index` is a bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: I have tried that but seems I have an error with ROW_NUMBER function.
Which is 'The function 'ROW_NUMBER' takes exactly 0 argument(s)'

Comment: @Gamer . . . Oops, there was a typo in the query.

Comment: Correct syntax is `row_number() over (partition by Col1 order by col3)`

Comment: Exactly, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to you use  `PARTITION BY` in you query

I hope could helped you.